# Want to convert very large html to pdf in core php

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, tcpdf, dompdf, mpdf

I am working in core PHP 5.5.9. I have very large html table which have more than 1 lack  rows. I have tried to do this approximately every plugin but can not able to achieve success.

I have tried :

[MPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf), [FPDF](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF), [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf),

[Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy), [TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF) and [phpwkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)

but can not able to convert this larg html to pdf.

Most found errors:

```
mpdf Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted

blank page
```

I have increase memory limit etc.

I have also try to divide into multiple small pdf and then merge all but it will take very large amount of time.

Can I convert very large(more than 1 lack lines) html into pdf using php?
Can I divide data into chunk for creating pdf?

Please Help. I appreciate all response. Thanks Ahead.

Comment: You _should_ see better performance by splitting up your HTML into multiple documents, rendering, then merging. I've used a similar process in the past with good results. Suggest upgrading to latest version of PHP and whichever library you settle on (wkhtml should be the most performant). Also try running each render in a separate process using `exec`.

Comment: Here's a relevant post from the Dompdf support forum: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dompdf/tvYDvZQ6u0E/discussion

Comment: @BrianS Thanks for giving me direction. I ll try it come to u again.